# Animated text ribbons in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three.js and not a math-superbrain. However, I challenge myself to learn it by building animated text ribbons.

What I'm trying to build is something like this:
[image]

The base idea:

1. Creating at least two smooth, fabric like ribbons along a custom path.
2. Front and backside of a ribbon can have different textures
3. The path of the ribbons should be closed so that I can show/hide segments in an endless animation.

The animation:

I'd like to show 1/3 of a ribbon and then animate along the path to reveal the next segments while hiding the previous ones. So the text/material appears to be in a static position in the room while the ribbon is revealed. If you look at my example below, I kinda achieve this using `setdrawRange`. However, I was not yet able to reveal the first segments again before the previous range has ended. That causes a jump in the animation at the end of the path.

Here's what I have so far:

Demo:
https://w73zt.csb.app/

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ribbons-w73zt

What I'm struggling with:

1. My approach was to use a TubeGeometry and give it only two radial segments. Is this legit, or is there a better way for what I'm trying to achieve?
2. Somehow I'm not able to put different textures on `FrontSide` and `BackSide` of that tube. And if I try to add them as an array according to the docs, no texture is shown at all. What am I missing here?
3. How can I use `setdrawRange` to create an endless animation effect without a jump at the end/start of the path? Hope it's understandable what I'm trying to say. The demo above should visualize the issue.
4. For some reason, the "close" option of the tube is creating a strange connection between the end and the start with fewer segments. This causes the texture to be stretched. How can I prevent this?
5. Is it beneficial to use SVG to render text like this or would you recommend another approach?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=curve#webgl_modifier_curve

Comment: Hey @prisoner849 - Yes I found that one as well. But I don't want to move the text along a path. I want to mask and unmask the path for a certain range while the texture remains steady at that path position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is very rough, unoptimized and imperfect option (not the ultimate solution at all, but at least a starting point), based on the source code of `ExtrudeGeometry` to form a ribbon, uses modified `MeshBasicMaterial` to cut the ribbon by the using of `discard`:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
console.clear();
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(5, 8, 13);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let grid = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 50);
scene.add(grid);

const pCount = 7;
let pts = new Array(pCount).fill(0).map((p, idx) => {
  return new THREE.Vector3().setFromSphericalCoords(
    5,
    Math.random() * Math.PI * (2 / 3) + Math.PI / 6,
    (idx / pCount) * Math.PI * 2
  );
});

let curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(pts, true);

const segments = 500;

let lpts = curve.getSpacedPoints(segments);
let lg = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(lpts);
let lm = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: "yellow" });
let l = new THREE.Line(lg, lm);
scene.add(l);

const frames = curve.computeFrenetFrames(segments, true);

let g = buildRibbon([
  { x: 0, y: 0.5 },
  { x: 0, y: -0.5 }
]);
let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg"
  ),
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  onBeforeCompile: (shader) => {
    shader.uniforms.time = m.userData.uniforms.time;
    shader.fragmentShader = `
      uniform float time;
      ${shader.fragmentShader}
    `.replace(
      `#include <clipping_planes_fragment>`,
      `
        if ( fract(time - vUv.x) < (2. / 3.)) discard;
        
      #include <clipping_planes_fragment>`
    );
    console.log(shader.fragmentShader);
  }
});
m.userData.uniforms = { time: { value: 0 } };
m.defines = { USE_UV: "" };
let r = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(r);

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop((_) => {
  m.userData.uniforms.time.value = clock.getElapsedTime() * 0.125;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

function buildRibbon(points) {
  let g = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, segments, 1);

  let ps = [];
  let P = new THREE.Vector3(),
    N = new THREE.Vector3(),
    B = new THREE.Vector3();

  points.forEach((p) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= segments; i++) {
      P = lpts[i];
      N.copy(frames.normals[i]).multiplyScalar(p.x);
      B.copy(frames.binormals[i]).multiplyScalar(p.y);
      ps.push(new THREE.Vector3().copy(P).add(N).add(B));
    }
  });

  g.setFromPoints(ps);
  return g;
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ahh, I was not aware of this `discard` approach. Definitely a good starting point! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Code snippet doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Now it works :)